# How to track/analyze GeoLocation requests in modern browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Modern browsers such as Firefox and Google Chrome offer a javascript API that, upon the users permission, can detect and share the user's location coordinates with the web server. But to do this, **it has to make an additional HTTP or other network request** to a web service. Is there an easy way to inspect this request for troubleshooting purposes? To see what is being sent, to where, and how long it is taking.

It does not show up in Firebug or the Web Inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a packet sniffer utility to analyze the raw network requests.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser engine works using its own logic.
The validated fonctionnality, **common to everyone**, is delivered with a lot of features (success, errors callback, watch, etc...) that can help you to troubleshoot it properly.

Please find below the mozilla doc about it if you want more informations.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_geolocation